# Error Handling in VBA when Connection is not present

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together a simple macro that does the following.

- Unlocks my password protected sheet
- Refresh a Query (Obtains info from an Access database on network drive)
- locks sheet with password.

I've put in an error handler to simply relock the spreadsheet and prompt a message box.  However that error handler doesn't work when there is no internet connection. It works fine if there is a network connection, and say for example I've moved the Access Database to a different location than the one stored in the Query.

I get a Run-time error 1004:
[DataFormat.Error] Your Network access was interrupted.  To continue, close the database, and them open it again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub RefreshItemTable()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

    Worksheets("Item List").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh

    On Error GoTo connError

    DoEvents

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

    Exit Sub

    connError:
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    MsgBox ("Unable to Connect")

End Sub
```

Comment: The error handler is only in effect after the `QueryTable.Refresh` method executes (and fails). Move the `On Error` statement to the top of the procedure, i.e. make it the first executable statement in the scope.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `On Error` statement the first executable statement in the procedure's scope.

The way you have it, you start handling errors only *after* `QueryTable.Refresh` runs (and fails).